# How do I print out 3 lines from a file simultaneously?

Tags: c++

I am trying to print out 3 lines in a file, but what ends up happening is it prints 1 of the lines in all 3 spots, the prints the second line in all three spots, and then, well, you guessed it, same with the 3rd.  I want it to print out all 3 lines in 1 push of the button.

```
ifstream read_file;
 string fname, name;
 cout << "Type the complete address of the file you would like to open.\n";
 cin >> fname;
 system("cls");
 read_file.open(fname.c_str());

 while(getline(read_file, fname))

 {
if (fname == "")continue;

cout << "You had "<< fname << " health left\n";
cout << "You delt " << fname  << " damage\n";
cout << "There were " << fname << " enemies left\n";
system("pause");
}


 read_file.close();
 system("pause");
```

Comment: not sure what you mean, can you give an example of what it's doing and what you want it todo?

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: We need to see your code so why not post the snippet of code that is doing the printing.

Comment: I'm trying to, the website isn't letting me post my code.  Give me a second.

Comment: From the limited amount of detail in your post, any ideas someone has would likely be closer to "moving on to the next question...". More detail would go a long way.

Comment: You are reusing the same variable. You need to use a different variable for each file.

Comment: Your question suggests that your file has 3 lines with one value on each (health, damage, then enemies), however your code calls `getline()` once, storing the line into `fname`, and then prints three lines from the same `fname`. Probably not what you intended.

Comment: How is the data in the file organized?  Do you want to write in columns?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your code

```
while(getline(read_file, fname))   
{
    if (fname == "")
        continue;

    cout << "You had "<< fname << " health left\n";
    cout << "You delt " << fname  << " damage\n";
    cout << "There were " << fname << " enemies left\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

it's fairly obvious that you're reading only one line, and printing it three times - you're not doing anything to `fname` between those outputs.

I recommend you stop reusing the same variable for multiple purposes, it's a source of many bugs.
(The following assumes that there are no blank lines.)

```
string health;
string damage;
string enemies;
while(getline(read_file, health) && getline(read_file, damage) && getline(read_file, enemies))   
{
    cout << "You had "<< health << " health left\n";
    cout << "You delt " << damage  << " damage\n";
    cout << "There were " << enemies << " enemies left\n";
}
```

If there are blank lines in the file, consider writing your own `getnonemptyline` function that skips blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Like molbdnilo said, you're only reading one line from the file and then trying to do three things with it.  If you wanted to keep re-using the same (oddly named) variable, you could do it like

```
while(getline(read_file, fname)){
    if (fname == "")continue;
    cout << "You had "<< fname << " health left\n";
}

while(getline(read_file, fname)){
    if (fname == "")continue;
    cout << "You delt " << fname  << " damage\n";
}

while(getline(read_file, fname)){
    if (fname == "")continue;
    cout << "There were " << fname << " enemies left\n";
}

system("pause");
```